# Cloud Functions for Firebase: retrieve the date of creation of a child from the database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to make a function that runs all the children from a certain node to perform something on those that were created exactly x days ago. I have already created a cron on my server to call the function once a day. My problem is that I do not find how to iterate all the children from a node and know their creation date. Is there a function to do this or do I have to put a field with the creation date?

Comment: You need to build a query that defines the nodes you're interested in.  You might want to read the docs and look at sample code for Firebase Realtime Database to learn how things work.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

Comment: @DougStevenson yeah, i have already do this but i don't how find their creation date

Comment: A query is not necessary when the parent node is known and all of the child nodes are to be iterated over.

Comment: @Jay , i know the parent node and i do a foreach in my function

Comment: If you know the parent node then you can directly access the node that has the children you want to iterate over. Queries tend to be more resource heavy so if you can use an observe event instead of a query, it's far more efficient. You can use a .child added event which will automatically iterate over all the children in the node and present them one at a time to where you can capture the data you need from each child such as the timestamp as shown in my answer. Check out the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data) for Listening for Child Events

Answer (score 0):

Add a timestamp (creation date) child to each node.

```
parent_node
    node_0
      timestamp: "20170328"
    node_1
      timestamp: "20170329"
    node_2
      timestamp: "20170330"
```

Then iterate over all the children of parent_node with .childAdded events or if it's a smaller number of nodes, use .value to load all of the children and iterate in code.