# Server side function : Leave only XX newest entries and delete all the rest

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cron

I return to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44260506).

I have the following structure. Each user has his own data.

```
---+ FB_ROOT_REFERENCE
   |
   +---+ Gy7FXRbRjDfAKWu7a95NgiGIZUk1  (Firebase User Id)
       |
       |
       +---+ KlNlb71qtQUXIGA4cNa (random key, generated by Firebase)
       |   |
       |   +--- (data field ...)
       |
       |
       +---+ KlNlcmfMTDjxQ0BwW1K
       |   |
       |   +--- (data field ...)
       |
       +---+ (...)
```

I've made some changes to the source code, but I do not know where to move next.

```
// Max number of lines
const MAX_RECORD_COUNT = 5;
const FB_ROOT_REFERENCE = '/locations';
// Removes siblings of the node that element that triggered the function if there are more than MAX_RECORD_COUNT.
// In this example we'll keep the max number of chat message history to MAX_RECORD_COUNT.
exports.truncate = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    const cron_key = req.query.key;

    // Exit if the keys don't match
      if (!secureCompare(cron_key, functions.config().cron.key)) {
        console.log('The cron_key provided in the request does not match the cron_key set in the environment. Check that', cron_key,
            'matches the cron.key attribute in `firebase env:get`');
        res.status(403).send('Security cron_key does not match. Make sure your cron_key URL query parameter matches the ' +
            'cron.key environment variable.');
        return;
      }

// Next
// need iterate all the children in (FB_ROOT_REFERENCE + user id)
// and keep MAX_RECORD_COUNT data children
// most recent and delete all the rest (older ones)
// ... 
// Here your code is required....

});
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me to write the source code. Thank you.

The code in this example will probably be useful "[Limit number of child nodes](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/limit-children)"

Comment: What's your question/problem?

Comment: I need to rewrite the trigger code to a normal function. but I dont know how.

Comment: If you want to run it in a regular node process, just remove the `exports.truncate = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {` line (and its closing `}` counterpart).

Comment: I need about the same as here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43080228